# Global setting of adjustwidth is ignored by figures

Tags: floats, margins, indentation

I have a long document which format I don't want to break. My aim is to shift the entire content to the right; so basically if I increase the right margin by `1cm` I want the left margin to decrease by the same amount. In this way the formatting and all the layouts will stay the same. I have used `\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{-1cm}` of *changepage* package in order to achieve this. The problem is that all the figures ( or I guess all the floats ) are ignoring this, and they are indented based on the old margins ( it can be clearly seen that caption right margin is `1cm` smaller than the rest of the document ). How can I achieve my aim of shifting EVERYTHING to the right by `1cm` while decreasing the left margin by the same amount. Here is some code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{-1cm} %<========================= works fine for everything except figures.
%% This actually creates the title and abstract pages
\dotitleandabstract

%% Generate contents etc
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

%% These include the actual text
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}

\bibliography{refs}             % this causes the references to be
                                % listed

\bibliographystyle{alpha}       % this determines the style in which
                                % the references are printed, other
                                % possible values are plain and abbrv
%% Appendices start here
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: we can not see anything from this test file as it can not be run. however to move everything to the right do not use `adjustwidth` just set `\hoffset` to the required length

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move everything to the right do not use `adjustwidth` just set `\hoffset` to the required length.